# How to start a Node REPL on Heroku?

Tags: node.js, heroku, read-eval-print-loop

Importing my app in a repl and calling its functions manually is super helpful for debugging and for fixing data. Can I do this remotely for a Node app?

In theory, I could probably do something like what those crazy Lisp hackers do:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "Vegas") { // don't do this in production
    app
    .use(authenticate())
    .use(userCan("repl"))
    .post("/command", (req, res) => {
        res.send(eval(req.body)); // hold my beer
    })
}
```

but then I have to either build a local REPL client or send each statement over curl. Surely I am not the first person to want a remote Node repl in an environment that does not support interactive debugging ([Interactively debugging a Node.js application on Heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25494402/interactively-debugging-a-node-js-application-on-heroku)). Has this been done before, in a saner way than this?

Comment: **Please avoid** usage of `eval()` like this. You are blindly executing arbitrary code that has access to your local scope and as such is a critical security issue.

Comment: I am aware of the dangers. The only proper use of eval that I have ever encountered, is for creating a read-**eval**-print-loop, which would be impossible without it. I this case, I actually want to execute arbitrary code in the same scope as my application, for the sake of debugging in an environment that I cannot replicate locally (Heroku). I'll wrap this in a default-off toggle though, just in case some 'tard copies this into a live app.